# UIPageViewController background never transparent in Objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want the background of `UIPageViewController` transparent so that I can see an image behind the `UIPageViewController` that will never move according to the scroll of `UIPageViewController`.

I tried many things including `[UIColor clearcolor]` but it will not show the content behind `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: add this line while your pageviewcontroller in viewdidload self.pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Already tried that, in both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear. It's not working.

Comment: show the view hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these solutions :

You need to clear color of PageViewContoller's item background color

**Solution 1**

Clear color through dataSource method of UIPageViewController .

## UIPageViewControllerDataSource

```
-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    PageViewController *itemPage = arrViewControllers[index];
    itemPage.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return itemPage;
}
```

**Solution 2**

While creating array for pageviewcontroller array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            PageItemViewController *pageItemController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageItemViewController"];
            pageItemController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            
            [arrViewControllers addObject:pageItemController];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like charm. It saved my day.

Comment: @DanielJames Welcome . it was my pleasure to helping you . Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this `self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;` in the ViewController which you inherit from PageViewController and every sub viewController and make backgroundColor of each clear.